# Which is the proper way to use locking inside of Parallel.ForEach?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, parallel.foreach, thread-synchronization

I would like to learn the best way to use locking in a `Parallel.ForEach`. Should I lock the whole code block inside of the iteration or should I only lock the object which I want to use as multi-thread safe before I do any process?

for example:

```
Parallel.ForEach(list, item =>
        {
            lock (secondList)
            {
                //consider other processes works in here

                if (item.Active)
                    secondList.Add(item);
            }
        });
```

or

```
Parallel.ForEach(list, item =>
        {
            //consider other processes works in here

            if (item.Active)
            {
                lock (secondList)
                    secondList.Add(item);
            }
        });
```

Comment: do you want to lock a collection?

Comment: Your first example would almost completely defeat the purpose of `Parallel.ForEach` in the first place. If more than one thread is used, they'll all be convoyed on the lock. Which suggests that this is probably a time to go and read up a lot more on Tasks, Task Parallel Library, maybe the Data Flow stuff, and work out if a lock has any place here at all.

Comment: not much difference with either version though.

Comment: You should use `ConcurrentDictionary` -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @Olegl yes, I want to lock a collection.

Comment: locking allows only one thread to enter the lock at a time completely defeating the benefits of Parallel.ForEach

Comment: @Nekeniehl yes but it's not the answer of my question. I want to learn the differences or the best way.

Comment: There is no much a difference between your both Parallel, I believe the first one is _more_ correct than the second one, as you don't access to the object `item`

Comment: @Nekeniehl thank you very much. I was afraid of it would be pointless to use the as first one as parallel usings.

Comment: Well..as the comment and answers already suggest, using parallelism and a lock doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: In the second example, you already have a `item.Active` property which triggers an item to be needed or not. You could just use the `item.Active` and make a selection after the parallel statement. (no locking needed)

Comment: @Nekeniehl thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

If your application concurrent(parallelism is one of the types of concurrency) and you want to use a thread-safe collection, there is no reason to lock collections on your own. There are bunch of concurrent collections provided by Microsoft which exist in System.Collections.Concurrent 
[Thread-safe Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/)

Comment: yes, but let's say I have to use List collections in my scenario. I don't want to change incoming data list type to Concurrent type, would it be bad for CPU using while type conversion?

Answer (score 2):

`Parallel.ForEach` is a way to try to get more parallelism into your code. `lock` tends to *reduce* parallelism in your code<sup>1</sup>. As such, it's rarely correct to want to combine them<sup>2</sup>.

As [Olegl suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54199402/15498), Concurrent Collections could be one way to go here to avoid the `lock`.

Another interesting approach would be to use [PLINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq) here instead of `Parallel.ForEach`. It's 2019 already, what's interesting about writing another loop?

This would do something like this instead:

```
secondList.AddRange(list.AsParallel.Where(item =>
{
    //consider other processes works in here

    return item.Active;
});
```

This allows you to keep your non-thread-safe `secondList` collection but still not worry about locks - because it's your own existing thread calling `AddRange` that ends up consuming that `IEnumerable<T>` that PLINQ offers; so only that one thread is adding items to the collection.

PLINQ tries to tune buffering options but may not achieve a good enough job, depending on the size of the input `list` and how many threads it chooses to use. If you're unhappy with any speedup from it (or it doesn't achieve any), try playing with the `WithXxx` methods it offers before writing it off.

---

If I *had* to pick between your two examples (assuming that they're both otherwise correct), I'd choose option 2, because it does *less* work whilst holding a lock that is being hotly contested by all of the other workers.

---

<sup>1</sup>Unless you know that all of the locks that will be requested are fine-grained enough that no two parallel threads will attempt to acquire the same lock. But if we know that, why are we using locks again?

<sup>2</sup>And so I'll go out on a limb and say it's "always" incorrect to combine them when all parallel locks are on the same lock object, *unless* there's significant processing happening in parallel outside of the `lock`.

Comment: I just wanted to understand where the locking should be. maybe if I can give another information about my scenario it would be much more help to us. it's not only about merge 2 different List collections, I have some other processes before added to list. I will share another scenario which contains same problem for me.

Comment: @CemÖnal - it's less about "where the locking should be" but more about "what are we locking on". As I hope I make clear in footnote 2, if all of the parallel items are locking on the same object, it would only (approximately) be right if there's significant processing happening *outside* of the lock itself. That would seem to make your example 2 more appropriate, if the comment about other code is hiding significant work. Basically, you should *always* want to do as little work as possible *inside* a lock.

Comment: I see, thank you for your detailed answers. then in my scenario using lock right before Add process would be much proper.

Comment: @CemÖnal - if this answer (or Olegl's) has been useful to you, you may want to consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Note that you can only accept one answer but you should vote up any answers that have been useful to you (once you have sufficient rep)

Answer (score 1):

For example that kind of usings:

```
public static T CastTo<T>(this ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstringKeyValueOfstringstring[] item)
    {
        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), true);
        var padlock = new object();

        Parallel.ForEach(typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public), prop =>
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                if (!prop.TryGetAttribute<GldnhrnFieldAttribute>(out var fieldAttribute))
                    return;

                var code = fieldAttribute?.Code;

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(code)) return;

                SetPropertyValue(item, obj, prop);
            }
        });

        return (T)obj;
    }
```

as you can see I want to cast my data to class over here. same question with different code block, should I lock all code block or should I lock only before calling SetPropertyValue method?

```
 public static T CastTo<T>(this ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstringKeyValueOfstringstring[] item)
    {
        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), true);
        var padlock = new object();

        Parallel.ForEach(typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public), prop =>
        {
            if (!prop.TryGetAttribute<GldnhrnFieldAttribute>(out var fieldAttribute))
                return;

            var code = fieldAttribute?.Code;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(code)) return;

            lock (padlock)
                SetPropertyValue(item, obj, prop);
        });

        return (T)obj;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is the second one:

```
if (item.Active)
{
    lock (secondList)
        secondList.Add(item);
}
```

The general advice is: do the least amount of work while holding the `lock`, and release it at the earliest opportunity. Don't do work inside the `lock` that can be done outside the `lock`.

Checking the `item.Active` does not require synchronization, so putting it inside `lock` is not needed. The more work that you put inside the `lock`, the more likely that another thread will be blocked while trying to acquire the same locker object. This is called **contention**, and slows down you application. You can get contention statistics by querying the [`Monitor.LockContentionCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor.lockcontentioncount) property before and after the parallel execution:

> Gets the number of times there was contention when trying to take the monitor's lock.

The smallest the delta (`after - before`), the better.